# In OpenShift Origin, I need to generate keys and certificates in order to make my connection secure. Where do these keys come from?

Tags: security, certificate, keys, openshift-origin

In OpenShift Origin, I need to generate keys and certificates in order to make my connection secure. Where do these keys come from?

These keys are in PEM format, and I really don't know where to find them or how to generate them.

I know semi-similar questions have been asked, but none that answer my question that I could find, and OpenShift's documentation isn't the best.

Preferably using the GUI and not command line, though I will if I must.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: At the most basic level, I am trying to have it so that when I click the route that brings me to a specific webpage (in this case, pgAdmin) it does not say "Not secure." Supposedly these certs need to be generated in order to be added to either the .yaml file of my pod, or perhaps placed in the route when I check the 'secure route' box and have a TLS termination set to 'Edge'. This is where I get lost. It says I need a PEM format certificate, a PEM format key, and 2 PEM format CA certificate chains.

Comment: You generally obtain those from a TLS certificate provider, at least for names on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

SSL keys infrastructure is meant to prevent man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks. Suppose you're a bank. A MITM can intercept traffic between you and your customer, impersonate you for your customer and impersonate your customer for you.

To do this, this man-in-the-middle will have to generate a secret key and encrypt the traffic between your customer and you with that key. However, browsers prevent MITM from doing that by requiring that your bank's server (and any other server) provides a certificate from a trusted third party that ensures that the key indeed belongs to the bank's server. MITM won't be able to obtain such a certificate, but you will be, if you're a valid bank server.

So, to protect your customers, you need to generate a private key and a certificate request.

1. Generate your private key (.key) and certificate request file (.csr) with:

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout <your_domain>.key -out <your_domain>.csr`

CSR-file is basically your plea to the certificating authority to verify that your key indeed belongs to bank, the owner of domain `<your_domain>`.

2. Send the CSR-file to the certificate issuing authority. That could be some SSL seller like COMODO or GODADDY. Alternatively, you can issue a self-signed certificate and verify (but browsers won't trust you, cause, you know, MITM can create a self-signed certificate too)
3. Authority will return a .CRT or .CER file with a signed certificate to you and also a set of upstream .CER files (authority can have no authority by itself either, but be delegated the privilege to sign and sell certificates by a higher-level authority - in that case you'll get 3 certificates - your own, intermediate - reseller's - certificate and root certificate of the 'real' authority).

You concat those 3 certificates (yours, than intermediate, than root) into a .PEM file and distribute it with your OpenShift server (go to Application -> Routes and press 'Edit' on that page to upload your private key and certificate chain).